# Why can't I send emails through amazon ses on Node?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm using "aws-sdk": "^2.117.0", my code looks like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.sendAWSMail = function(message, destination){
  const ses = new AWS.SES();
  // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property
  const sendEmail = ses.sendEmail;
  var data = {
    Destination: {
     ToAddresses: [
        "blahblah@gmail.com"
     ]
    },
    Message: {
     Body: {
      Html: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>."
      },
      Text: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "This is the message body in text format."
      }
     },
     Subject: {
      Charset: "UTF-8",
      Data: "Test email"
     }
    },
    Source: "no-reply@frutacor.com.br",
   }
  sendEmail(data)
}
```

But I get this error:

TypeError: this.makeRequest is not a function
    at svc.(anonymous function) (/Users/iagowp/Desktop/trampos/frutacor/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:499:23)

I didn't find any Node examples at their website, but from what I've seen elsewhere (like [here](https://jaketrent.com/post/send-email-aws-sdk-node-example/)), it looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is in line #5 and it's always a good idea to add the callback function for logging errors and successful requests.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.sendAWSMail = function(message, destination){
  const ses = new AWS.SES();
  var data = {
    Destination: {
     ToAddresses: [
        "blahblah@gmail.com"
     ]
    },
    Message: {
     Body: {
      Html: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>."
      },
      Text: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "This is the message body in text format."
      }
     },
     Subject: {
      Charset: "UTF-8",
      Data: "Test email"
     }
    },
    Source: "no-reply@frutacor.com.br",
   }
   ses.sendEmail(data, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but would you be able to explain why that line fails me? Anyways, that really was my problem, now I get a more helpful error message I can work with (need to set region)

Comment: Once you set the region, it should work like a charm.

Comment: I'd love if you elaborated on the reason line 5 was wrong. It worked, thanks

Comment: Don't know for sure, it didn't look right to me. Maybe if you've set it to a var not const it might have worked! Sorry, I wish I was of bigger help. Thankfully it's blue fixed :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, and re-reading the error message, taking a method out of its original context and not having it bound, it should lose access to the other methods the class had.

Comment: Is it possible to send a n attachment using this SES+ nodejs